# Chrome extension: append to url before page loads

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

thank you for reading my post. i'm super new to javascript. i'm trying to build a chrome extension that force safe search by appending a string to the url before the page loads. I have the following code and I have no idea why it does not work. would anyone be able to help? I would really appreciate it.

```
{
  "name" : "Force SafeSearch",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version" : "1.0",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs"],
  "host_permissions" : ["https://*.google.com/*"],
  "description" : "Enables SafeSearch on Google, YouTube and Bing.",
  "background.service_worker": {
      "scripts": [ "forceSafeSearch.js"]
  },

  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon-16.png",
    "32": "images/icon-32.png",
    "48": "images/icon-48.png",
    "128": "images/icon-128.png"
  }
}
```

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.update({ url: tab.url.padEnd(12,'&safe=active') })
});
```

Best,

Terry

I tried different listeners, and putting the code outside the listen, but nothing really worked.

Comment: Remove `background.service_worker` block from manifest.json and delete forceSafeSearch.js. Use declarativeNetRequest as shown in [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/), also find examples that use `addOrReplaceParams`.